# Сложить два числа в виде массивов цифр разной длины поэлементно

Tags: c, массивы, адрес

на вход подаются два числа разной длины **в виде массива цифр**
их длины и адрес длины массива суммы и адрес самого массива суммы

пример число `12345` в виде массива `[1 2 3 4 5]`
а число `69`    в виде массива `[6 9]`

```
   на выходе должно быть `1 2 4 1 4`
```

найти сумму и разность чисел

ниже код для суммы

Индексация **только через** адреса. Никаких счетчиков типа `int i=0; i<summ_len; i++`

```
void sum(int *data1, int len1, int *data2, int len2, int *summ, int *summ_len){

    for (int *p = summ; len2 - (p - summ) > 0; p++) { // ту некорректно! на этой строке мои полномочия всё!
                       
    }
}
```

Comment: А как вы на бумажке будете складывать многозначные числа? Вот примерно так же и  с массивами работайте

Comment: тут складываение не поэлементно. Если бы было поэлементно, то результат бы был "1 2 3 10 14".

Comment: мне не нужно 14 и 10. в массиве только цифры. я могу реализовать через индексацию. но нужно через адреса!

Comment: О том Вам и говорят - у Вас не поэлементное сложение массивов

Comment: Покажите, что у вас получается через "индексацию"